# Saving ggplot as SVG ruins quality

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, png

I have a plot generated from the following code:

```
bars <- ggplot(plottingFrame, aes(x=X, y=as.factor(Y))) +
                                         geom_raster(aes(fill=colour)) + scale_fill_identity())
```

Where plottingFrame is a load of colour values precomputed. geom_raster is used with scale_fill_identity to make a "heatmap" of different colours:

[image]

Ignore the squashed axis and cutoff titles, I made the image smaller so it's not too big.

The above image is what happens when ggsave is used on the bars object and it is saved as a png.

When I try to use ggsave to save as svg however, it blurs the colours between the three coloured rows.
Why does saving a geom_raster based plot blur the three rows - Seq1, Seq2, and Seq3, when png keeps them distinct as in the above image? And how can I stop saving to sag blurring them?

Thanks,
Ben W.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hey, maybe you can 'grid.export' from the 'gridSVG' package a try, but due to the fact, that svg is a vector format and your example pretty much looks like a raster image would be more appliccable.
Due to the fact that ggplot2 builds on grid this would be my choice.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll give your solution a try and report back!

Comment: Did it work? You can also rvg or ggsave